# How to anotate ServiceWorker with flow?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, flowtype

I'm trying to get 100% code coverage with flow but I'm stuck with anotating my ServiceWorker. It is not throwing any errors, but all `self.addEventListener(...)` are marked as uncovered. For example in:

```
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  console.log("Event: Install");

  event.waitUntil(
    //Open the cache
    caches
      .open(cacheName)
      .then((cache) => {
        //Adding the files to cache
        return cache.addAll(filesToCache).then(() => {
          console.log("All files are cached.");
          return self.skipWaiting(); //To forces the waiting service worker to become the active service worker
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  );
});
```

Even if I do something like `let a = self` flow will show this line as uncovered.

I tried changing `self` to `this` but that didn't help either :(

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like Flow doesn't have `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope` class yet. But it has [WorkerGlobalScope](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.46.0/lib/bom.js#L431) with addEventListener. Try to use it `let a = (self : WorkerGlobalScope)`. If flow show errors — use hack with any `let a = ((self : any) : WorkerGlobalScope)`